# grpc - Invert Request/Response flow: server requests, clients responds

Tags: networking, grpc

As explained in the [grpc overview](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/), the default flow is that a client connects to the server and sends requests, to which the server responds adequately (well, hopefully).

I'm interested in using grpc for a new project, but the flow must be inverted. I want the client to answer questions. But it can't be the server since it'll be hidden behind firewalls and may not listen on ports.

The flow I need is:

1. Server is listening as usual
2. Client connects to the server as usual
3. From then on, the server asks questions (sends requests), and the client answers them, and not the other way around as is usual.

Is there a way to do that with grpc? It can involve network configuration on the server side, but none is possible on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

gRPC natively supports bi-directional streaming. And what you need can be achieved by that.

- Client connects to server, wait to read server message (questions)
- Server asks questions (sends messages to client)
- Client replies (sends messages to server)

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need to do. But I couldn’t find it in the documentation. Any pointers?

Comment: https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#server-streaming-rpc